# Run YouTube video smoothly in Android TV

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-tv

When I try to run a YouTube video inside Android TV application the video is running so roughly.

Before 3 months I was using YouTube Android API to run the video on the same device but this library is fully deprecated now.

My code is the very base code from YouTube API (iframe) page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          playerVars: {
            'playsinline': 1
          },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

then I load this code inside a webview like this:

```
 WebView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video);
        videoView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        videoView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        videoView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        videoView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);

        String html = getPageHTML();
        videoView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

where html is the previous code

NOTES:
1- I have tried 3rd party libraries and the same result is happening every single time
2- In manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

hope you can help me to find a way to run the video smoothly

Comment: Youtube uses different codec for videos, and your device may not support decoding some of the codes with hardware decoder. You need to first check the video codecs and the your device capabilities to make sure that the decoding is not done in software.